# Motivation of Vieta's transformation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, math-history, cubics, motivation

The depressed cubic equation $y^3 +py + q = 0$ can be solved with *Vieta's transformation* (or *Vieta's substitution*)

$y = z - \frac{p}{3 \cdot z}.$

This reduces the cubic equation to a quadratic equation (in $z^3$).

Is there any geometric or algebraic **motivation** for this transformation? I am not asking why this transformations works - this is just an easy calculation. I would rather like to know how to come up with it. Perhaps even how and when Vieta came up with it. I haven't found anything about the history of this transformation, except that it probably wasn't invented by [Vieta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Vi%C3%A8te).

Notice that the Ansatz $y = z + \frac{c}{z}$ for a constant $c$ will eventually lead to $c = -\frac{p}{3}$, but what *motivates* this Ansatz - except for that it works in the end? Here is what I guess (but this is not convincing yet): Polynomial transformations do not work, so let's try rational transformations. Try to keep the degree low.

I am aware of Galois theory and how it helps to understand the cubic from a highly conceptual point of view, but I would like to avoid Galois theory here.

Any information about the history of this transformation will also be appreciated.

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=306173

Comment: Well, this is the connection to Cardano's resp. Tartaglia's method. But these are even less motivated, in my opinion. In texts the story is usually told as: Let's try $y=u+v$ and see what happens. See, it works! But this is no motivation (for me). Ideally, I would like to see an argument of the form: The cubic function *has to be* composed with $z + \frac{c}{z}$ because ..."

Comment: OK, then, try this: http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/solving-the-cubic-with-cardano "I want to think along with Cardano, to understand his solution as he did, and to bring my students to an understanding of Cardano’s world of mathematics—his ways of thinking and the mathematical tools at his disposal.  The elucidation of these points is my goal in this article."

Comment: Have you had a look at the maa link?

Comment: Yes. It is quite interesting that Cardano's proof uses solid geometry as a motivation. I was hoping for something more analytic. Maybe this is too naive.

Comment: Now one can combine Cardano's motivation with Vieta's transformation to get a motivation of Vieta's transformation. I wonder: Is there an independent way?

Comment: I can say that this substitution you mentioned was not by chance.  It is a special case of a "general substitution" method.  I had done this in my papers.  Because there is a different type of substitution to reduce the cubic equation to quadratic.  And it can never be derived from the  substitution $y=z-\frac{p}{3z}$ or $y=\frac pz-\frac z3$ by any algebraic manipulation.

Comment: This is related to how if $x=a+b$ then $x^3=a^3+b^3+3abx$. That's also how you find stuff like $\sqrt[3]{9+4\sqrt{5}}+\sqrt[3]{9-4\sqrt{5}}=3$. To solve the cubic you want $y=z+a/z$ so that when you cube it $y^3=z^3+a^3/z^3+3ay$ the linear term in $y$ vanishes, then you choose $a$ accordingly. I don't know if a deeper explanation exists.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: If you're interested in the actual historical context, then perhaps the dedicated [History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange](http://hsm.stackexchange.com) would be a good place for this question.

Comment: @Derivative Your first equation has a nice geometric interpretation: put two cubes of size $a$ and $b$ in a cube of size $a+b$, and look at the rest: three congruent cuboids.

Comment: It's anachronistic, but: a way to understand solution of the cubic that is (to my taste) reasonably innocent/natural is by "Lagrange resolvents" (e.g., as in van der Waerden's "Algebra", and as in my own on-line algebra notes). I can make an answer in such terms if you'd think it worthwhile.

Comment: @paulgarrett Thanks, but my question is not "how to solve the cubic equation easily", it's specifically about the Vieta transform.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, ah, ok. My impression is that Vieta (and comrades) were really implacable ... :)

Comment: @paulgarrett Indeed, the approach is more systematic with the Lagrange resolvents, and also provides better insight into why it works for cubics and quartics but not for the general quintic.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Viète's motivation came from the solution of the following problem:

*Find two numbers when their sum and the sum of their cubes are given, i.e., find $x$ and $y$ such that*
$$x+y=a, \qquad x^3+y^3=d$$
A simple solution is to factor the last expression:
$$\begin{align}x^3+y^3&=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2) \\ &=(x+y)((x+y)^2-3xy) \\ &=a(a^2-3xy)=d\end{align}$$
We can now find
$$xy={a^3-d \over 3a}$$
and the problem is reduced to the much simpler one of solving the equations $x+y=a$ and $xy=b$, which Viète had already considered.

Viète now realized that he had a very nice relation between the sum of two numbers, the product of the two numbers, and the sum of their cubes, given by
$$a^3 - 3ba = d$$
Hence, if he had an equation on this form, where $a$ was the unknown, he could solve it by finding $x$ and $y$ such that $a=x+y$ and $b=xy$. This leads to the substitution
$$a = x + {b\over x}$$
The equation then becomes
$$x^3+{b^3\over x^3}=d$$
which gives $d$ as the sum of the cubes, and which is a quadratic in $x^3$.

*Edit:* [The Analytic Art](https://books.google.it/books?id=omHqrYBzMpAC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Viète is available online. The motivating example is on p. 110, and this solution of the cubic equation is on p. 289. Viète's methods are also explained in Victor Katz: [A History of Mathematics. An Introduction](https://books.google.no/books/about/A_History_of_Mathematics.html?id=h50fAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y).

Comment: Very nice answer. Could you provide a reference? (+1)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer I have added some references to the answer.

Comment: Utter brilliance

Comment: Nicely done, including the references (+1).

Comment: @PerManne: Many thanks for the interesting references. :-)

Comment: I am very happy for this simple and complete answer. Thank you @PerManne

Answer (score 3):

Vieta's own motivation was nicely covered in [@PerManne](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/33572/per-manne)'s answer. The following is another take on a plausible algebraic insight, which uses nothing that wouldn't have been familiar to Vieta.

Suppose that a root of the depressed cubic $\,y^3+py+q=0\,$ is in the form $\,y=\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}\,$, which would not have been an unreasonable assumption in those times [1].

Then, with $\,u=a+b, v=ab\,$, it follows that:

$$
\begin{align}
y^3 \;&=\; \left(\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}\right)^3 \;=\; a + b + 3\sqrt[3]{ab}(\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b})
 \;=\; u +3 \sqrt[3]{v}\,y
\\ & \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\iff \;\;\;\;\;\; y^3 - 3 \sqrt[3]{v}\,y - u = 0 \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

For $\,(1)\,$ to match the original equation, thus ensuring $\,y\,$ is a root, it is sufficient that:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
-u &= q
\\ -3 \sqrt[3]{v} &= p
\end{cases}
\;\;\;\;\implies\;\;\;\;
\begin{cases}
u &= -q
\\ v &= -\dfrac{p^3}{27} \tag{2}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

It follows that $\,a, b\,$ are the roots of $\,t^2+qt-\dfrac{p^3}{27}=0\,$, which is the same quadratic derived from Vieta's (and others') methods.

Moreover, letting $\,z=\sqrt[3]{a}\,$, it follows from $\,(2)\,$ that $\,\sqrt[3]{b}=-\dfrac{p}{3z}\,$, so $\,y=\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}=z-\dfrac{p}{3z}\,$ not only justifies Vieta's form, but also makes the meaning and symmetry more explicit.

[1]  Quoting Friedrich Katscher from [How Tartaglia Solved the Cubic Equation - Tartaglia's Solution](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/how-tartaglia-solved-the-cubic-equation-tartaglias-solution):

> *The quadratic equation has a solution in the form of a binomio $a+\sqrt{b}$ or of a residuo $a−\sqrt{b}$. This suggested that cubic equations might also have a solution in the form of a binomio or of a residuo, however, with cube roots instead of quadratic ones. Probably Tartaglia tried the different possibilities, and thus found that the residuo $\sqrt[3]{a}−\sqrt[3]{b}$ and the binomio $\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}$ led to the solutions he sought.*

---

[ *EDIT* ]   One other less obvious motivation for Vieta's $\,z\,$ substitution in preference to the $\,\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}\,$ form used in Tartaglia and Cardano's methods is that it avoids the ambiguity in the choice of cube roots when the roots of the quadratic are (non real) complex. Once one of the cube roots is chosen as $\,\sqrt[3]{a}=z\,$, the other one gets necessarily chosen as $\,\sqrt[3]{b} = -\frac{p}{3 z}\,$.

Comment: For historical interest, [here](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/how-tartaglia-solved-the-cubic-equation-tartaglias-poem) is Tartaglia's poem describing his solution to the cubic.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to discover Vieta's transformation.  Start with the classical Chebyshev polynomial $T_n(X)$, which satisfies $T_n(\cos\theta)=\cos n\theta$.  It is well-known that

$$T_n\Bigl(\frac{X+X^{-1}}2\Bigr)=\frac{X^n+X^{-n}}2.$$

[One way to deduce this is to write $z:=e^{i\theta}$, so that $\cos\theta=(z+1/z)/2$ and $\cos n\theta=(z^n+1/z^n)/2$, which means the above identity holds when $X$ takes each of the infinitely many values $e^{i\theta}$ -- so subtracting the right side of the identity from the left yields a rational function whose numerator has infinitely many roots, and hence is the zero polynomial.]

In case $n=3$, this identity says

$$(4X^3-3X)\circ\frac{X+X^{-1}}2 = \frac{X^3+X^{-3}}2,$$

or equivalently

$$ (X^3-3X)\circ (X+X^{-1}) = X^3+X^{-3},$$

which yields Vieta's substitution in case $p=-3$.  To obtain similar substitutions for an arbitrary $X^3+pX$, just conjugate the above identity by $rX$ to get

$$ \Bigl(rX\circ (X^3-3X)\circ X/r\Bigr) \circ \Bigl(rX\circ (X+X^{-1})\circ X/r\Bigr) = rX\circ (X^3+X^{-3})\circ X/r,$$

which simplifies to

$$ (r^{-2}X^3-3X) \circ (X+r^2X^{-1}) = r^{-2}X^3+r^4X^{-3}.$$

Now multiply by $r^2$ to get

$$ (X^3 - 3r^2 X) \circ (X+r^2 X^{-1}) = X^3 + r^6 X^{-3}.$$

Writing $p:=-3r^2$, this becomes

$$ (X^3 + pX) \circ \Bigl(X-\frac{p}{3X}\Bigr) = X^3 - \frac{p^3}{27X^3},$$

which is Vieta's identity.

So one can view Vieta's substitution as being a change of variables of the identity $\cos 3\theta=4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta$.

I note that one can similarly solve any equation of the form
$T_n(X) = q$ by substituting $(X+1/X)/2$ for $X$ to get
$X^n + X^{-n} = 2q$, yielding a quadratic polynomial in $X^n$.  The unusual feature of the case $n=3$ is that every degree-$3$ polynomial is a linear change of variables of either $X^3$ or $T_3(X)$, so that the fact we can solve $T_n(X)=q$ and $X^n=q$ implies we can solve every degree-$3$ polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

In the notation of
$$p=-\dfrac34r^2\tag1$$
the given cubic takes the form of
$$4y^3-3r^2y+4q=0,$$
or
$$4\,\dfrac{y^3}{r^3}-3\,\dfrac yr + \dfrac{4q}{r^3}=0.\tag2$$
Let
$$y=r\cosh t =\dfrac r2\left(e^t+e^{-t}\right),\tag3$$
then from $(2)-(3)$ should
$$\cosh 3t + \dfrac{4q}{r^3}=0,\quad \dfrac{r^3}8\left(e^{3t}+e^{-3t}\right)+q=0.\tag4$$
Assuming
$$z=\dfrac r2\,e^t,$$
easily to get
$$y=z+\dfrac{r^2}{4z}=z-\dfrac p{3z},$$
$$z^3-\dfrac{p^3}{27z^3}+q = 0.$$
This makes clear the Vieta's substitution.

Comment: Thanks. But here we even have more steps with little motivation. How to come up with (1) and (3)?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thank you for the comment. I've tried to show Vieta's motivation. Formulas $(1)-(4)$ are similar to Vieta's trig substitution.