# Consider the binomial expansion of $(m+n)^3$. Consider the equation $(m+n)^3-3mn(m+n)-(m^3+n^3)=0$. Using the equation solve $x^3-6x+7$ in exact form.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

using vietas transformation solve $x^3-6x+7$ in exact form.

The factor theorem won't work, as it doesn't factorize. It's known as a depressed cubic equation. Please help.
EDIT: Sorry I'm new to this. Putting the equation into DESMOS the only value for $x$ is $-2.901$ (3dp).

Comment: What have you tried? Did you consider their hint? If yes, what are you stuck at?

Comment: To avoid closing, show some of your effort at solving.

Comment: The hint makes no sense to me either, but if you change the problem to one of solving $x^3+6x+7$, it becomes much easier to solve (although the hint still seems overkill). Think about how you could get $-7$ as the sum of two cubes (where you are allowed to take the cube of a negative number). I suspect the negative sign before $6x$ is an error in the problem statement.

Comment: @DavidK There is definitely no error in the problem statement. Do you know any ideas or methods where I can use the hint?

Comment: @CalvinLin I've edited it with some of my recent working, but I still don't know how to apply the hint. Any ideas?

Comment: By "error in the problem statement" I merely meant that it does not work the way it was intended to work. I gather that you have checked your transcription and it is accurate. Therefore the error (if there is one) was made before the problem was presented to you. It is also possible that the problem statement is exactly what is is meant to be and that the solution given by dxiv is the one intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to make sense of the hint would be to look for $\,m,n\,$ such that:$$(m+n)^3-3mn(m+n)-(m^3+n^3) = (m+n)^3 - 6 (m+n) + 7$$

Identifying coefficients of $(m+n)$ gives $\,mn=2\,$ and $\,m^3+n^3=-7\,$. Eliminating $\,n = \dfrac{2}{m}\,$ between the two equations:
$$
m^3 + \frac{8}{m^3} = -7 \;\;\iff\;\; m^6 + 7 m^3 + 8 = 0
$$

The latter is a quadratic in $\,m^3\,$, so:
$$
m^3 = \frac{-7 \pm \sqrt{17}}{2}  \;\;\implies\;\; n^3 = \frac{8}{m^3} = \frac{-7 \mp \sqrt{17}}{2}
$$

Then the real root of the original cubic is:
$$
x = m + n = \sqrt[3]{\frac{-7 + \sqrt{17}}{2}} +  \sqrt[3]{\frac{-7 - \sqrt{17}}{2}}
$$

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4194739/291201) is a step-by-step of how this works for depressed cubics in the general case.

Comment: +1. 1) I would think it might be worth pointing out for the OP that this is one possible general way of deriving the general formula of the cubic equation. e.g. $x^3+px+q=0$ and comparing $(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)-(a^3+b^3)=0$ assuming that root is $x=a+b$ and we have $2$ complex solutions, since $m^3=a$ has $3$ roots . 2) Maybe OP might want how to $\frac {8}{m^3}= \frac{-7 \pm \sqrt{17}}{2} $, one way would be $$m^3\cdot n^3 =8\\ m^3+n^3=-7$$ which implies, $m^3$ and $n^3$ are the roots of $u^2+7u+8=0$ which yields $u_1=m^3$ and $u_2=n^3$ .

Comment: Ahh, after that comment, I saw  your comment .

Comment: @lonestudent Indeed, that's covered in the answer linked in my first comment.